# Swap multiple rows at same time using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items and i want to set the order of items in list.
If i select multiple items at same then the multiple items should move respectively up or down.

I am using this code to move up and down. but in this case if first and third item are selected then it returns false because i am adding a check that if previous to current item is null then it should not move that up and if next to current is not available then it should not move down.

```
$('#selectedTab tr').each(function () {

            var currentTr = $(this).find('td.backgroundcolor').parent();
            if (currentTr.text() == null) {
            }
            else {
                debugger;
                var previousTr = "";
                if (obj.value == "Move Up") {
                    previousTr = currentTr.prev();
                    //if (previousTr.length == 0)
                    //    return false;
                }
                else {
                    previousTr = currentTr.next();
                    if (previousTr.length == 0)
                        return false;
                }
                var temp = currentTr.contents().detach();
                currentTr.append(previousTr.contents());
                previousTr.append(temp);
            }

        });
```

And Html for this

`

```
        <table id="unSelectedTab" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/Employees.png" />Employee</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/vehicles.png" />Vehicle</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/collision.png" />Collision</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/trailers.png" />Trailers</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/dispatch.png" />Dispatch</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/notifications.png" />Notifications</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/equipment.png" />Equipment</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
```

`

Thanks 
Prince Chopra

Comment: <tr>
                    <td>
                        Employee</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
@Palash Mondal

Comment: So what should happen when you select item number 2 and 4 and then click "Move up"? Item number 2 should be the new number 1 and item number 4 the new number 3? What should happen if one of the selected items is already first or last item?

Comment: in that case i need to move the 3rd one to the 2nd position and 1st one remains at 1st. @Gorgsenegger

Comment: So what is the exact problem then? You already check for the special cases first and last item. And why don't you use != null for your if and remove the empty branch, you don't Need it.

Comment: actually when it goes to first and second position then it swaps with first and second . first goes to second position and second goes to first position.@Gorgsenegger

Comment: When you select both first and second item and then "move up"? What is the desired result in that case? Please update your question with these special cases and the respective desired outcome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29851/discussion-between-gorgsenegger-and-prince-chopra)